# React Hook Form - Rules.Validate not triggered

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I have the following field with a RHF controller and a MUI Textfield:

```
<Controller
  control={control}
  name="name"
  defaultValue=""
  rules={{
    required: true,
    minLength: 3,
    maxLength: 300,
    validate: wtf,
  }}
  render={({ field, fieldState: { error } }) => (
    <TextField
      {...field}
      fullWidth
      label="Name"
      size="small"
      helperText={formState?.errors?.name?.message}
      error={error !== undefined}
    />
  )}
/>
```

The wtf method isn't getting called on input change. I've tried with different revalidate modes but this is just not firing at all. Am I missing something here? I've checked examples and tutorials and they all seem to do it this way.

Comment: can you tell us what is wtf method? Its actually code.

Comment: @ChetanKondawle wtf() just replaces a validation method for the field, it's just a test method that console.logs the input value. However it's not even getting called so I don't think the error is there.

Comment: have you tried removing other validations max, min and required and only keeping validate?

Comment: @ChetanKondawle Yes, still same issue.

Comment: Hi! Did you find my answer useful or do you need further clarification @DevT ?

Answer (score 13):

I created a sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-rules-validate-not-triggered-pcnzhs?file=/src/App.js) and it works perfectly.

I only had to add `{mode: "onChange"}` inside the `useForm` method call and return a `string` if the validation function failed.

I based my improvements in the documentation for [register options](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register) as it is recommended [here](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller/controller) in the rules section of the Controller component.

Feel free to ask for any further help.

-Ado

Comment: `{mode: "onChange"}` was a trick. Thanks!

Comment: I love you man, you really helped me with this answer ❤️

Comment: That's nice to hear! If you need any further help do not hesitate to ask!

Comment: wasted a day before coming here. Thanks

Comment: I tried so many things, but only ```const { control } = useForm({ mode: 'onChange' });``` solved my problem. Thanks